# python sql query stating 'not enough input arguments'

Tags: python, mysql

In order to select the price of an item I have the following code:

```
product = ['user_input']
item(product)
day = int(self.ui.spinBox.value())

query = 'select price from (select * from %s order by count limit %d) order by count as limit desc'

sql = query % item % day
```

In response I get the error that there aren't enough input arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify multiple arguments as tuple, eg:

```
sql = query % (item, day)
```